# How to clear inflate error in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am creating a layout and a `ListView` within it to display small icon in 5 columns. I am using `AysncTask` to parse `JSON` to get the images details which I need to display in list view. Now I am getting error. I don't know how to solve. Please help me to solve.

My layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_seatvisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.notebook.runtowin.Activity.Seatvisible">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/from_to"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="Select your seat"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorwhite" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/from_to">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#FFEB3B"
            android:id="@+id/headinglayout">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/busname"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:text="RUN TO WIN"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@+id/busname"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/seatnumber"
                    android:padding="5sp"
                    android:text="Seats :"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@+id/seatnumber"
                    android:text="25,24"
                    android:id="@+id/seatsnumber"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ticketprice"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="hsdshd"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="5sp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10sp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headinglayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
            android:paddingTop="10sp"
            android:paddingRight="25sp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp">

            <ImageView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@drawable/iconsteer"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginEnd="50sp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/listviewseat">

            </ListView>


        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25sp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            >
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BOOK TICKETS"
                android:padding="10sp"
                android:id="@+id/bt_book"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Listview Layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8sp"
    android:gravity="top">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewseat"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My code is:

```
public class Seatvisible extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> busdetails1;

private String BusID, servicedate;
private static String url="http://appsilonz.com/demo/v2/bus_seat_abhi.php?journey_date=2017-01-05&bus_id=20";
private ListView lv;
private TextView busname, from_to, seatsnumber, ticketprice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seatvisible);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewbusdetails);
    inilize();

    new Seatparsing().execute();

}

private void inilize() {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    BusID = intent.getStringExtra("BusID");
    servicedate = intent.getStringExtra("servicedate");
    busname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.busname);
    from_to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.from_to);
    seatsnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seatsnumber);
    ticketprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ticketprice);


}

public class Seatparsing extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    String response;
    String jsonstr, seat_name, ticket_status, seatladies;
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Seatvisible.this);
    AndroidHttpClient maclient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        try {
            response = maclient.execute(request, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        Log.i("Seats", "" + response);
        Log.i("seaturl", "" + url);

        jsonstr = response;
        busdetails1 = new ArrayList<>();

        if (jsonstr != null) {

            HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray(jsonstr);
                for (int i = 0; i < array1.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject objct1 = array1.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray array2 = objct1.getJSONArray("row1");
                    for (int j = 0; j < array2.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject objct2 = array2.getJSONObject(j);

                        seat_name = objct2.getString("seat_name ").toString();
                        ticket_status = objct2.getString("ticket_status");
                        seatladies = objct2.getString("seatIsLadies");

                        map2.put("seat_name", seat_name);
                        map2.put("ticket_status", ticket_status);
                        map2.put("seatIsLadies", seatladies);

                    }
                    busdetails1.add(map2);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return busdetails1;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> busdetails1) {


        dialog.dismiss();

        customadapter adapter = new customadapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.seatlistview, busdetails1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

public class customadapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public customadapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> busdetails1) {
        super(context, resource, busdetails1);

        list = busdetails1;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewseat);

        String seat_name = list.get(i).get("seat_name");
        String ticket_status = list.get(i).get("ticket_status");
        String seatIsLadies = list.get(i).get("seatIsLadies");

        if (!seat_name.equals(null)) {

            if (ticket_status.equals("booked")) {
                if (seatIsLadies.equals("true")) {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.reservedladies);
                    imageView.setClickable(false);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookedseat);
                    imageView.setClickable(false);
                }

            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.available_seat_img);


            }

        } else {

            imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
            imageView.setClickable(false);


        }


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use dp instead of sp for any dimensions other than text size

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dp` for dimensions and `sp` for `textSize`. Currently you are using `sp` for dimensions.

See the edited layout below,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_seatvisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.notebook.runtowin.Activity.Seatvisible">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from_to"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Select your seat"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorwhite" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/from_to">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFEB3B"
        android:id="@+id/headinglayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/busname"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="RUN TO WIN"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/busname"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/seatnumber"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Seats :"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="25,24"
                android:id="@+id/seatsnumber"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ticketprice"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="hsdshd"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headinglayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp">

        <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/iconsteer"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/listviewseat">

        </ListView>


    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BOOK TICKETS"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/bt_book"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

For ListView layout,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:gravity="top">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewseat"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also you can't `layout_marginRight` to an `id` at this line,

```
android:layout_marginRight="@+id/seatnumber"
```

You probably meant,

```
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
```

See @**Baseem Samy's** answer too.

Comment: that's true, but the error wasn't because of sp it's because he set a margin right to an id

Comment: @BassemSamy Oh I Missed that!

Comment: @Bassem,Neeraj,uguboz..thankyou...its working ...bt now the activity is visible and after few seconds it gone to previous page.i debuge and find that i got an error in ayanctask parsing on "return busdetails" in background..i updated my code..

Comment: @kavin Show the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

I see sp units in ur layout files for padding size. sp is for font size only where dp or dip is for all dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

in the textview with id  android:id="@+id/seatsnumber"
you set layout_marginRight to an id, that's not available in android you can't set a padding with a view

```
 <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@+id/seatnumber"
                    android:text="25,24"
                    android:id="@+id/seatsnumber"/>
```